# How do i change Rails routing from controller/:id to controller/:name in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Just as the topic say. I want to change the default controller/:id routing to controller/:name instead in Rails 3. In Rails 2 you used named routing with something like this:

**config/routes.rb**

```
map.location 'location/:name', 
  :controller => 'your_controller', :action => 'your_action'
```

**alternate named route**

```
map.location 'goto/:name', :controller => 'location', :action => 'your_action'
```

**examples of URL specification in a view**

```
<%= link_to 'foo', location_url({:name => 'foo'}) %>
<%= link_to 'bar', location_path({:name => 'bar'}) %>
```

But i'm sure there is another (better) way in Rails 3.

Answer (score 4):

If the :name is a unique identifier of the object, you can you https://github.com/norman/friendly_id for general permalink support for ActiveRecord.

Just by specified

`has_friendly_id :name`

you'll get automatically routing like

http://example.com/states/washington

instead of

http://example.com/states/4323454

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may this would help you.

match 'user_delete/:name', :to => 'sessions#destroy'

this is same as

map.user_delete '/user_delete/:name', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match 'location/:name' => 'your_controller#your_action', :as => location
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have location.name, then you could link_to it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'foo', location_path(location.name) %>
```

will give you the url /locations/:name

as opposed to

```
<%= link_to 'foo', location %> #same as <%= link_to 'foo', location_path(location) %>
```

which will give you /locations/:id